# Calculations are all over the place. Math Wizzes needed

Tags: javascript

The function is not calculating properly!

For context:
The cost of a first class fare is 2 times the cost of an economy class fare.
The cost of a business class fare is 1.5 times the cost of an economy class fare.
The cost of a return fare is 2 times the cost of a one-way fare.

Route Cost of one-way economy class fare (base cost)
Hawkins - Riverdale $229
Hawkins - Haddonfield $259
Hawkins - Rockwell $199
Hawkins - Eagleton $179
Hawkins - Pawnee $179
Hawkins - Twin Peaks $239

The function should be adding the selected options and displaying the total.
What is wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <script>
        function calculation() {
            var cost = 0; //Base cost of flight (one way Economy)
            var radioButton; // A radio button
            var selection = 0; // The selected radio button, 1 to 6 going down.
            for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {// Get the number of the selection (1 to 6)
                radioButton = document.getElementById("destination" + i);
                if (radioButton.checked == true) {
                    selection = i;
                }
            }
            if (selection == 1) {
                cost = 229
            } else if (selection == 2) {
                cost = 259
            } else if (selection == 3) {
                cost = 199
            } else if (selection == 4) {
                cost = 179
            } else if (selection == 5) {
                cost = 179
            } else if (selection == 6) {
                cost = 239
            } else if (selection == 0) {
                alert("Please select a flight.");
                return false;
            }
            var seating = 0;
            for (var x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
                radioButton = document.getElementById("seating" + x);
                if (radioButton.checked == true) {
                    seating = x;
                }
            }

            var totalcost = 0;
            if(seating == 0){
                alert("Please select a seat.");
                return false;
            } else if(seating == 1){
                totalcost = cost + (cost * 2);
            } else if(seating == 2){
                totalcost = cost + (cost * 1.5);
            } else if(seating == 3){
                totalcost = cost;
            }


            if(document.getElementById("return").checked){
                totalcost = totalcost*2;
            }
            totalcost = totalcost + cost;
            alert("Total cost: "+totalcost);
        }

    </script>
    <body>
        <h1> Hawkins Airlines Fare Calculator</h1>
        <p> Complete the form below to calculate the cost of your flight.</p>

        <form onsubmit="return false;">
            <p>Route:</p>
            <input type="radio" name="destination"  id="destination1"> Hawkins - Riverdale<br>
            <input type="radio" name="destination"  id="destination2"> Hawkins - Haddonfield<br>
            <input type="radio" name="destination"  id="destination3"> Hawkins - Rockwell<br>
            <input type="radio" name="destination"  id="destination4"> Hawkins - Eagleton<br>
            <input type="radio" name="destination"  id="destination5"> Hawkins - Pawnee<br>
            <input type="radio" name="destination"  id="destination6"> Hawkins - Twin Peaks<br>
            <br>

            <input type="checkbox" name="appliances" id="return">
            <label>Click here if you will be purchasing a return fare </label><br>

            <p>Seating class:</p>
            <input type="radio" name="seating"  id="seating1"> First seating<br>
            <input type="radio" name="seating"  id="seating2"> Business seating<br>
            <input type="radio" name="seating"  id="seating3"> Economy seating<br>
            <br>

            <button onclick="calculation()"> Calculate </button>
            <input type="reset" value="Restore Defults">
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is radioButton and what is Selection because what is on your questions details are not in the function itself please fix your variables naming and your Question title

Comment: [Your code works](https://jsfiddle.net/fs5v6ryk/) but for some reason you're doubling the total right at the end (`totalcost = totalcost + cost;`) so maybe remove that.

Answer (score 2):

This is provided you have proper backend validation:

```
<form onsubmit="return false;">
            <p>Route:</p>
            <input type="radio" name="destination" value="229" id="destination1"> Hawkins - Riverdale<br>
            <input type="radio" name="destination" value="259" id="destination2"> Hawkins - Haddonfield<br>
            <input type="radio" name="destination" value="199" id="destination3"> Hawkins - Rockwell<br>
            <input type="radio" name="destination" value="179" id="destination4"> Hawkins - Eagleton<br>
            <input type="radio" name="destination" value="179" id="destination5"> Hawkins - Pawnee<br>
            <input type="radio" name="destination" value="239" id="destination6"> Hawkins - Twin Peaks<br>
            <br>

            <input type="checkbox" name="appliances" id="return">
            <label>Click here if you will be purchasing a return fare </label><br>

            <p>Seating class:</p>
            <input type="radio" name="seating" value="2" id="seating1"> First seating<br>
            <input type="radio" name="seating" value="1.5" id="seating2"> Business seating<br>
            <input type="radio" name="seating" value="1" id="seating3"> Economy seating<br>
            <br>

            <button onclick="calculation()"> Calculate </button>
            <input type="reset" value="Restore Defults">
</form>
```

The value of both the cost and seating is set on the radio button itself so that you can easily read the selected value and avoid having to iterate through all the buttons.

```
function calculation() {
  //select selected radio buttons
  const selectedRoute = document.querySelector('input[name="destination"]:checked')
  const selectedSeatingClass = document.querySelector('input[name="seating"]:checked')
  const isRoundTrip = document.querySelector('input[name="appliances"]').checked

  //show "Select route" alert if no route is selected
  if (selectedRoute === null) {
    alert('Select route')

    //do not continue calculation
    return false;
  }

  //Do the same, just for seating
  if (selectedSeatingClass === null) {
    alert('Select seating class')

    //do not continue calculation
    return false;
  }

  //grab values off selected radio buttons
  //wrap them in Number to get a numeric value because
  //you always get string when reading a value off an input
  const cost = Number(selectedRoute.value)
  const seatingMultiplier = Number(selectedSeatingClass.value)

  const price = cost * seatingMultiplier

  isRoundTrip ? alert(price * 2) : alert(price)

}
```